# async wp_head() content manually

Tags: wordpress, seo

I'm doing some SEO page load stuff, and one of the things that google suggest is adding asyng to the script tags to they load the page faster.

Heres the suggestions:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fhardscapedesigns.com%2F&tab=desktop

Most of the stuff I'm trying to edit is generated by wp_head function. Does anyone know how I can add async to those script tags, I'm not able to find the exact place to edit that HTML. I know there some plugins that supposably do this, but I'd rather do it manually since they seem to break my site

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `async` keyword in your script tags. Using a plugin for such petty tasks is very wastefull.

Your script tags should look something like this-

```
<link async type="javascript/text" href="THE_URL"/>
```

Comment: right, thats what im trying to do, but the script tags are being generated by wp_head() function. its not like i can just go into the theme editor and edit  script tag, i need to find it somewhere... thats what my whole question is. where do i edit the content that is being outputed by the wp_head function?